# Can we Host ASP.NET SignalR v2.4.1 in an ASP.NETCORE App?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, .net-4.7.2, signalr-2

I have a situation where my codebase is stuck in .Net 4.7.2 for now but I need to push some notifications on a Website which is built on Asp.Core 2.2.

Across the system we use SignalR 2.4.1 but it is completely re-written in .Net Core.

I tried hosting it in the same app without success. Owin does not seem to be happy.

Has anyone had any success with it or has any suggestion?

There has to be a way for projects migrating from .Net to Core.
Thanks

Comment: You want to push notifications from a .NET FW app to an .NET Core app?

Comment: correct, essentially its a core app website communicating with a .net API and I want to push notifications from the API project to the (core)website

Comment: Why you just not develop a .net core microservice to push notifications? it can be generic as you want and push notifications to all plataforms. I ask because this can be out of question...

Comment: I see your thiking here, the problem is that its a single API project and 6 websites in front of it all hosted in IIS not in containers. Unless I am missing something, this is not possible  withthe current setup as the notification microservice would have to be hosted independently right?

Comment: `its a core app website communicating with a .net API and I want to push notifications from the API project to the (core)website` I'd like to confirm these information with you: 1) your hub server is built with asp.net signalr 2) and now you want to implement real time notification functionality in your .net core website to make your .net core website can also receive notification sent from asp.net signalr hub server

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after along night I got a solution to this issue.

First just to make my setup clear.
There is an API project targetting .Net 4.7.2 which is broadcasting some messages via a SignalR 2.4.1 Hub.
There are some other Asp.Net 4.7.2 Projects consuming those Hubs which are working fine.
And also there is a new website build in .Net Core but targetting 4.7.2 framework.

The solution I ended up is essentially hosting an OWIN pipeline within the AspCore Pipeline.

First I needed to install the following packages:

- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin

I also added a new extension method for the Core IApplicationBuilder interface that sets up OWIN on the same pipeline:

```
    public static class OwinExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseOwinApp(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<IAppBuilder> configuration)
        {
            return app.UseOwin(setup => setup(next =>
            {
                IAppBuilder owinApp = new AppBuilder();

                var aspNetCoreLifetime = (IApplicationLifetime)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IApplicationLifetime));

                var owinAppProperties = new AppProperties(owinApp.Properties)
                {
                    OnAppDisposing = aspNetCoreLifetime?.ApplicationStopping ?? CancellationToken.None,
                    DefaultApp = next
                };

                configuration(owinApp);

                return owinApp.Build<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>>();
            }));
        }
    }
```

Then in the **Startup** class of the Core project, in the **Configure** method I was able to use my extension and register SignalR hubs to it like this:

**Startup.cs**

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            ...

            app.UseOwinApp(owinApp =>
            {
                owinApp.MapSignalR();
            });

            ...
}
```

This way we can add more middlewares to the OWIN pipeline if we need to for whatever reasons.

I hope this helps.